# Flickrapi e fotos de um usuário específico com Python

Tags: python, api

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem?

Preciso pegar algumas fotos de [um usuário específico do FLICKR](https://www.flickr.com/photos/marcozeroconteudo) e com uma descrição específica para um trabalho de faculdade.
Ainda estou aprendendo a programar, então não sei muito bem como fazer, tentei ler as orientações de API, mas não entendi bem. O máximo que consegui baixar foram algumas fotos com uma "keyword" específica, mas o conteúdo não bate exatamente com o que preciso. Tentei colocar várias keywords ou tentar adicionar o nome da fotógrafa, mas não consegui baixar nenhuma foto.
Acredito que resolveria o problema se eu puxasse apenas as fotos de um usuário específico com a descrição que preciso, é possível fazer isso com o [flickrapi](https://pypi.org/project/flickrapi/) ou outra api?

*#id da marcozeroconteudo: **152991702@N05***

[Aqui](https://www.flickr.com/photos/marcozeroconteudo/49483456936/in/photostream/) envio um exemplo de foto que preciso baixar. E as descrições do texto são essas:

> Marco Zero Conteúdo Suape,16 de agosto de 2018. Estaleiro Atlantico
> Sul. Crédito: Keila Castro/MZ Conteúdo
>
> As tags dela são: **Suape, Estaleiro, Atlantico Sul**

```
import flickrapi
import urllib
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# image.load_img()
#id da marcozeroconteudo: 152991702@N05

# Flickr api access key 
flickr=flickrapi.FlickrAPI('MINHA_API_KEY', 'MINHA_API_SECRET', cache=True)


N_MAX = 500
keyword = 'Estaleiro Altantico Sul'


PHOTOs = flickr.walk(text=keyword,
                     tag_mode='all',
                     tags=keyword,
                     extras='url_c',
                     per_page=108,           # may be you can try different numbers..
                     sort='relevance')

urls = []
for N, PHOTO in tqdm(enumerate(PHOTOs)):
    
    url = PHOTO.get('url_c')
    urls.append(url)
    
    # get 50 urls
    if N > N_MAX:
      break
print (urls)


# Download image from the url and save it to '00001.jpg'
#urllib.request.urlretrieve(urls[0], '00001.jpg')
RESIZE_OPTION = Image.ANTIALIAS #Image.NEAREST, Image.BICUBIC

for i in range(N_MAX):
  fname = f'img_{keyword}{i}.jpg'
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(urls[i], f'img{keyword}_{i}.jpg')
# Resize the image and overwrite it

image = image.open(fname) 
image = image.resize((256, 256), RESIZE_OPTION)
image.save(fname)
```

**Agradeço desde já pela ajuda,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaproveitando seu código

Importando as bibliotecas necessárias:

```
import flickrapi
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
```

Autenticação:

```
api_key = u'API_KEY' # passando em formato unicode
api_secret = u'API_SECRET' # passando em formato unicode
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret, cache = True)
```

Tags que serão buscadas:

```
tags = ['Suape', 'Estaleiro', 'Atlântico Sul'] 
photos = flickr.walk(tag_mode='all',
                     tags = tags,
                     extras='url_c',
                     per_page=100)
```

Pegando as urls, neste caso só insiro as com 65535, que é um padrão da url do usuário que você deseja pegar as imagens:

```
urls = []
for i, photo in enumerate(photos):
    user = '65535'
    try:
        url = photo.get('url_c')
        if user in url:
            urls.append(url)
    except:
        pass
```

Baixando as imagens e salvando no diretório em que o script está sendo executado:

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    try:
        name = str(i) + '.jpg'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, name)
        image = Image.open(name) 
        image = image.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(name)
    except:
        pass
```

---

Removi a api_key e secret ja que a pergunta foi atualizada para não prejudicar o autor da pergunta.